# Can I use collectors in java to find a document with max value of a key from a list of documents

Tags: java, collections, max, comparator

I have an `ArrayList` of documents in Java.
I want the document which has the max value of a key, say `nameId`.
Can I use collectors to find this in the shortest possible way?

My code works fine, but I am looking for a better way to do this.

```
//ArrayList<Document> documents
//above is the list of documents i have
HashMap<String, Document> map = new HashMap<>();
documents.forEach(doc -> map.put(doc.getString(nameId), doc));
String maxNameId = Collections.max(map.keySet());
Document docWithMaxNameId = map.get(maxNameId);
```

The code returns the correct value, but I am wondering if there is another way using collectors to solve this problem in a single line or a shorter way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it maybe belongs on code review.

Comment: If `documents` is an `ArrayList<Document>` and `maxNameId` is a `String`, how can `documents.get(maxNameId)` be a valid call? Did you mean `map.get(maxNameId)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to collect to a HashMap:

```
Document docWithMaxNameId =
    documents.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(doc -> doc.getString(nameId))
        .get();
```

Comment: "No need to collect to a HashMap" couldnt agree more. another approach would simply be using the `Collections.max` overload which takes a comparator as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned no need to collect to a `HashMap`.

You may be surprised but there's already a `Collections.max` taking a comparator:

```
Document doc = Collections.max(documents, Comparator.comparing(d -> d.getString(nameId));
```